# Representation of spatial lines with altitude

Tags: r, sp

Is there any R data structure that supports spatial lines that include height information? I'm looking for something like `SpatialLinesDataFrame` with support for altitude in the lines. Associating a time with each point would be nice but not essential.

My data is airplane flight tracks. I want to be able to do spatial analysis such as finding the ground distance and altitude at the closest point of approach to a fixed point on the ground, and visualizations such as maps where the segments are coloured by altitude.

The data is supplied as KML files. Currently I am using `rgdal::readOGR` to read the lat/lon data and metadata, and `maptools::getKMLcoordinates` to read the same data as a data.frame containing lat/lon/altitude. This works but it is awkward to use two data structures to contain pieces of the same data.

Any suggestions?

(I originally posted this on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33190522/representation-of-spatial-lines-with-altitude) but no answers there...)

Comment: Are the elevations defined at the nodes of the lines, or are line segments at a constant defined height, or does the height change along line segments? I can see various ways of doing it depending on how the elevation is related to the lines...

Comment: The elevations are defined at the nodes - I have a sequence of lat / lon / altitude points. The points are close enough that I can assume straight lines between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the advent of the [simple features for R](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) package, this is straighforward. LINESTRING objects may have four dimensions x, y, z, t. Sometimes the `st_zm` function is needed to strip z, t for use in e.g. mapping.

Answer (score 3):

I'd denormalise it into a data frame of `x`, `y`, `z`, `time`, `id` columns. Then a path is simply the 3d set of `x`,`y`,`z` locations, ordered by `time`, within the same `id` value.

If you need the altitude info in a "linesy" object then you'll need to construct line segments with an initial elevation and final elevation attribute.

Comment: Yes, that sounds better than the list of dataframes I am using.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing for elevation, so you need to indeed to read this in separately and make it an attribute. However, you can do time. See the `spacetime` package.

Comment: Thanks, without the altitude data `spacetime` and `trajectories` are not really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `spacetime` you may want to look at package `trajectories`, it has a vignette with some plots with colored line segments.